# Did Cops have an episode in which a woman's baby was taken from her for "lying to the police"?

Tags: television, police

> [image: Screenshot of the tweet: "COPS came on before The Simpsons when I was a kid, so I used to catch the end of it sometimes. I’ll never forget the episode I saw where they took a woman’s baby away from her for “lying to the police.” She was begging and sobbing, and they got it on video. Fuck that show."]
> <sub>[Mara “Get Rid of the Nazis” Wilson](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mara_Wilson) via [Twitter](https://twitter.com/MaraWilson/status/1270530973344518145) (19k likes; 2k retweets), and posted on [Reddit's r/Bad_Cop_No_Donut](https://www.reddit.com/r/Bad_Cop_No_Donut/comments/jgd1o0/im_so_happy_cops_got_canceled/) (20.1k likes)</sub>

I couldn't immediately verify this claim; I didn't find a link in the comments at Twitter or Reddit (although I didn't search comprehensively).

**Question**: Did [Cops](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cops_(TV_program)) have an episode in which a woman's baby was taken from her for "lying to the police"?

Comment: It’s maybe relevant to note that Mara was born in 1987. She was 13 in 2000 and 18 in 2005, just for an idea of what “when I was a kid” might mean.

Comment: It's quite possible that what actually happened was that the cops were serving a warrant to take the child away, and the mother made false statements during the encounter. That could cause a confusion as to the real reason for the removal.

Comment: Interesting question, but this might be better in [Movies and TV](https://movies.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: Isn't cops somewhat scripted as well? Don't they do a lot of added BS for drama?

Comment: @DenisS This question is off topic for Movies & TV as it is an identification question. It is on topic here given the number of likes/upvotes on the claim and its repost.

Comment: @Laurel really? I thought ID questions were fine for Movies and TV.  I must be wrong.

Comment: The relevant policy at Movies.SE is here: [We are discontinuing support for identification questions](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4087/we-are-discontin%E2%80%8C%E2%80%8Buing-support-for-identification-questions).

Comment: Not a direct answer, but I clearly recall the podcast "Headlong: Running from Cops" discussing a situation very similar to this one. I can't recall which episode of cops it was though.